# tricky InterlockedDecrement vs CriticalSection

Tags: c++, winapi, thread-safety

There is global `long count` counter.
Thread A does

```
EnterCriticalSection(&crit);
// .... do something
count++;                       // (*1)
// .. do something else
LeaveCriticalSection(&crit);
```

Thread B does

```
InterlockedDecrement(&count); // (*2) not under critical secion.
```

At (*1), I am under a critical section. At (*2), I am not.

Is (*1) safe without `InterlockedIncrement()` ? (it is protected critical section).
Do I need `InterlockedIncrement()` at (*1) ?
I feel that I can argue both for and against.

Comment: I presume the lock there because of the `// do something` code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use one or the other, not mix them.

While `InterlockedDecrement` is guaranteed to be atomic, `operator++` is not, though in this case it likely will be depending upon your architecture.  In this case, you're not actually protecting the `count` variable at all.

Given that you appear to want to do simple inrecrement/decrement operations, I would suggest that you simply remove the critical section in this case and use the associated `Interlocked*` functions.

Answer (score 4):

Both threads should use **either** `InterlockedDecrement`/`InterlockedIncrement`, **or** the same critical section. There is no reason for the mixing and matching to work correctly.

Consider the following sequence of events:

```
Thread A: enter the critical section
Thread A: read count into a register
Thread A: increment the value in the register
Thread B: InterlockedDecrement(&count) <<< There's nothing to stop this from happening!
Thread A: write the new count
Thread A: leave the critical section
```

**Net result: you've lost a decrement!**

A useful (if deliberately simplified) mental model for critical sections is this: all entering a critical section does is prevent other threads from entering the same critical section. It doesn't automatically prevent other threads from doing other things that may require synchronization.

And all `InterlockedDecrement` does is ensure the atomicity of the decrement. It doesn't prevent any other thread performing computations on an outdated copy of the variable, and then writing the result back.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you do.

#### Otherwise it could be that:

1. The value is read
2. The value is incremented atomically
3. The original value is incremented and written, invalidating the previous atomic update

Furthermore, you need the *same* critical section for both, since it doesn't help to lock on separate things. :)